# I keep getting this error when I write the code but when I copy paste error is gone I checked each number and letter one by one

Tags: javascript-objects

`document.getElementById("num1-el")?.textContent` this is the written one

`document.getElementById("num2-el").textContent` this is the copy pasted one

In the terminal I get this error:

> The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.

Comment: Well, that depends on the context where you use these expressions. The error message tells me you tried something like `document.getElementById("num1-el")?.textContent = "foo bar"` which is not allowed, because the object which you are trying to change may be undefined. Notice the `?` in the first statement, which isn't there in the second?

Comment: problem is that the project is defined. When I copy and paste the second code on new projects too it works but typing it down I get that error

Comment: That's maybe because your ide inserts the `?` automatically ...

Comment: when it ? the code does not work